# Refresh one lookup data

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Using Anywhere - work execution app (v7.5.2), Refresh look up data option refresh the complete look up data. How to refresh only one look up which often changes like ITEM for Actual Materials ?
Ex:
If i assign a new device, every time technician need to do REFRESH LOOK UP to get the latest assigned item in look up. How to mitigate this in 7.5.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

In our current releases there's no way without downloading all the lookup data.  You can reduce the amount of lookup data being downloaded to the device by using the Anywhere Admin app to make the lookup data refresh faster.  We have an enhancement request to support delta download of the lookup data in our backlog.